# Load a hash on grouped_collection_select rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently, I have a hash like this:

```
@lg = {
  "Latin East Group" => [
    {:id => 2, :name => "HONGKONG"},
    {:id => 3, :name => "NINGBO, ZHEJIANG"},
    {:id => 4, :name => "SINGAPORE"},
    {:id => 5, :name => "LARCHMONT, NY"},
    {:id => 6, :name => "CHICAGO, IL"},
    {:id => 7, :name => "HAIPHONG"},
    {:id => 8, :name => "DANANG"},
    {:id => 9, :name => "HANOI"},
    {:id => 10, :name => "MARSEILLE"},
    {:id => 11, :name => "LONDON"},
    {:id => 12, :name => "EDINBURGH"},
    {:id => 13, :name => "AMSTERDAM"},
    {:id => 14, :name => "HOCHIMINH"},
    {:id => 15, :name => "SHANGHAI"}
  ],
  "Latin West Group" => [],
  "Others" => [
    {:id => 16, :name => "Brazil" },
    {:id => 17, :name => "Mexico" },
    {:id => 18, :name => "Columbia"}
  ]
}
```

Now, I am using select2 with my form, and I wanna create a dropdown menu from that hash instance variable. I want the keys of the hash will be the optgroups, and the option values are gonna be the name sin the hash like Singapore, Brazil... Therefore, I am wondering what is the correct syntax for it. Currently, this is my code:

**_form_body.haml**:

```
 %div.col-md-8
    = f.grouped_collection_select :origin_locations, @lg, @lg.keys, @lg.values, {:selected => f.options[:origin_locations]}, {class: 'form-control select2-multiple origin_locations', :multiple => true}
```

**pricing_histories_controller.rb**:

```
def load_location_groups
  @lg = {}
  location_groups = LocationGroup.all.includes(:locations).each { |group|
    @lg[group.name]= group.locations.map{|l| {id: l.id,name: l.name}}
    }
    # location_groups.each_with_index do |location_group, index|
    arr = Location.where("id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(location_id) FROM location_group_assignments)").pluck(:id,:name)
    @location_groups = {}
    @lg["Others"] = arr.map{ |e| {id: e.first, name: e.last}}
end
```

I will get the error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (["Latin East Group", "Latin West Group",
>   "Others"] is not a symbol nor a string)

So, I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks and have a nice day.